# Scala case class with multiple-type argument

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I need to check integrity of nested schemas and hence am writing case classes to do so. The main hurdle I am facing is the schema may have a field (say, `name`) either of a `String` or a `Utf8` type and I want to accept both the instances. Is it possible to avoid having two case classes as

```
 case class NameValueString(name: String, value: Double)
 case class NameValueUtf8(name: Utf8, value: Double)
```

and something like

```
 case class NameValue(name @(_:String | _:Utf8), value: Double)
```

The above expression certainly fails compilation.

Nikhil

Comment: I would create a new constructor

case class NameValueString(name: String, value: Double) {
  def this(name: Utf8, value: Double) = this(name.toString, value)
}

Is it valid for you?

Answer (score 4):

One approach is so-called type classes:

```
trait StringLike[A] // sealed if you don't want anybody to implement it elsewhere
object StringLike {
  implicit object StringEv extends StringLike[String] {}
  implicit object Utf8Ev extends StringLike[Utf8] {}
}

case class NameValue[A](name: A, value: Double)(implicit val stringLike: StringLike[A])
```

Of course, `StringLike` will normally not be empty, but describe whatever common functionality you need from both `String` and `Utf8`.

You can match on the evidence:

```
def nameLength[A](nameValue: NameValue[A]) = nameValue.stringLike match {
  case StringLike.StringEv => 
    nameValue.name.length // calls String#length
  case StringLike.Utf8Ev =>
    nameValue.name.length // calls Utf8#length (assuming Utf8 has such method)
}
```

In this case the compiler will even know that `A` (and so the type of `nameValue.name`) is `String` in the first branch and `Utf8` in the second.

Comment: Good answer. I'd just like to add that you can use the "context bound" syntax to achieve the same result: `case class NameValue[A : StringLike](name: A, value: Double)`

Comment: `implicit val utf8: StringLike[Utf8] = new StringLike[Utf8] {}` I suppose?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I am trying your suggestion. Just one question, how would the pattern-matching query look like? `case x: NameValue => ...` doesn't sound write to the compiler without the template/type parameter :(.

Comment: @stefanobaghino If you want to actually use the evidence using context bound and `implicitly` will hurt performance.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi That's the place where this pattern gets ugly. You can't match in trait since `ClassTag` bound is not allowed in traits and `A` is erased. So you need to define your method 4 times: abstract in `StringLike[A]`, concrete in implicits (only you will need `object`, not `val`) and once more in `NameValue` to call the method from `StringLike[A]` using the evidence.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi Don't pattern match. Delegate the work to the actual typeclass instance.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi I've extended the answer to show how to pattern-match, but go with Alvaro Carrasco's reply first.

Comment: @VictorMoroz There's no usage of `implicitly`. Furthermore, how is it slower? Consider that a context bound is desugared in an implicit evidence and that implicits are resolved at compile-time.

Comment: @stefanobaghino `implicitly` is  a method: http://blog.vmoroz.com/posts/2016-08-09-using-context-bound-and-implicitly-in-scala.html. Also, you have to use the evidence (i.e. implicit parameter) as your methods will be inside a type class instance. If you use a context bound the only way to get it is  via `implicitly`.

Comment: What would be the right part of your `case` clauses? `asInstanceOf[String]`? `A` is a parameter (I assume `def foo[A]...`)

Comment: @VictorMoroz Thanks for sharing, I learned something new. However, I'd still prefer to use context bounds when there's no reference to the evidence (and thus no price to pay for a method call, just the benefit of a clearer syntax).

Comment: @VictorMoroz No need for `asInstanceOf`, that's the point of the next sentence.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like a dark magic and I find it completely unreadable, the same expression `nameValue.name` means different things in two consecutive lines. You are right, it works. But I would prefer adding `ClassTag[A]` to `nameLength` and explicit pattern match if I ever want to go in that direction (see my update).

Answer (score 2):

Another pattern (doesn't require implicit arguments):

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class StringLike[A](name: A) {
  override def toString = {
    name match {
      case s: String => s"String: $s"
      case i: Int => s"Int: $i"
    }
  }
}
implicit def string2StringLike(s: String) = new StringLike(s)
implicit def int2StringLike(i: Int) = new StringLike(i)

case class NameValue[A](name: StringLike[A], value: String) {
  override def toString = name.toString
}

NameValue("123", "123")
//> NameValue[String] = String: 123
NameValue(13, "123")
//> NameValue[Int] = Int: 13
NameValue(13.9, "123")
// error: type mismatch;
//  found   : Double(13.9)
//  required: StringLike[?]
//      NameValue(13.9, "123")
//                ^
```

**UPDATE**

Here's how I see completed type class approach based on Alexey's answer:

```
trait StringLike[A] {
  def toString(x: A): String
}

object StringLike {
  implicit object StringStringLike extends StringLike[String] {
    def toString(s: String) = s"String: $s"
  }
  implicit object IntStringLike extends StringLike[Int] {
    def toString(i: Int) = s"Int: $i"
  } 
}

import StringLike._

case class NameValue[A](name: A, value: Double)(implicit ev: StringLike[A]) {
  override def toString = ev.toString(name)
}

NameValue(1, 2.0)
//> NameValue[Int] = Int: 1

NameValue("123", 2.0)
//> NameValue[String] = String: 123

NameValue(2.0, 2.0)
// error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: 
// StringLike[Double]
//       NameValue(2.0, 2.0)
//                ^
```

**UPDATE2**

One more (using [union type](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) for type safety):

```
type ¬[A] = A => Nothing
type ¬¬[A] = ¬[¬[A]]
type ∨[T, U] = ¬[¬[T] with ¬[U]]
type |∨|[T, U] = { type λ[X] = ¬¬[X] <:< (T ∨ U) }

def nameLength[A: ClassTag: (Int |∨| String)#λ](nameValue: NameValue[A]) =
  nameValue.name match {
    case s:String => s.length
    case i:Int => i + 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using case class already, if you just need different ways to create it, and you are ok on keeping your data represented in only one way, you can add your own apply method to enable the creation using different parameters.

```
 case class NameValue(name: String, value: Double)
 object NameValue{
     def apply(name: Utf8, value: Double): NameValue = {
         new NameValue( name.toString, value )
     }
 }
```

Alternatively, if you would like to pattern match and extract NameValue from different options, you may need to check Extractors, which is basically create your own unapply methods... check http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html